# Printing index positions

Tags: python

I am given the following list

```
mylist=[25,42,58,31,20,11,42]
```

which I separated them into a new list

```
newlist=[[25,42,58,31],[20,11,42]]
```

Then I need to print it as follow. How do I code it in a way where all the index will be printed?

> First sequence is : 0,1,2,3
> Second sequence is : 4,5,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this only depends of `newlist` (i.e `newlist` is a valid split of `mylist`):

```
newlist=[[25,42,58,31],[20,11,42]]
start = 0
for i, l in enumerate(newlist):
    seq = range(start, start+len(l))
    start += len (l)
    print(f'sequence {i} is: {",".join(map(str,seq))}')
```

Output:

```
sequence 0 is: 0,1,2,3
sequence 1 is: 4,5,6
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is one implementation using `itertools.count`:

```py
import itertools

newlist=[[25,42,58,31],[20,11,42]]

cnt = itertools.count()
for i, sublst in enumerate(newlist):
    print(f"Sequence {i}:", [next(cnt) for _ in sublst])

# Sequence 0: [0, 1, 2, 3]
# Sequence 1: [4, 5, 6]
```

I personally find this method concise.

Comment: Nice one, should have thought of it ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a list of lists that you could interate through and count the results.

```
addition = 0
for idx, item in enumerate(newlist):
    if idx != 0:
       addition = len(newlist[idx-1])
    print(f"Sequence of item {idx+1}: {[i+addition for i in range(len(item))]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`inflect`](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) package to convert 1, 2, 3 to 1st, 2nd, 3rd...

Quick prototype:

```py
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

for i in range(len(newlist)):
    print(f"{p.ordinal(i)} sequence is {','. join(map(str , seq))}}")
```